# java embedded key-value data store for counters

Tags: java, embedded-database, key-value-store

I am searching for an embedded key-value data store which

1. has Java API
2. easy to manipulate counters (a.k.a. SET value=value+10 WHERE key="k")
3. support multi-threads clients
4. High performance

I have found [LevelDBJni](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni), but it is designed for simple K-V operation and unfriendly for counters. Are there better solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the Java library you can use a `Map` with an `AtomicInteger` as value.

*In the following examples I use `String` as datatype for the key.*

E.g.

```
Map<String, AtomicInteger> kvStore = new ...
```

To manipulate the counters you can then use

```
kvStore.get("...").addAndGet(10);
```

To retrieve also the updated value

```
AtomicInteger value = kvStore.get("...").addAndGet(10);
```

As `AtomicInteger` is designed for concurrency a multi-threaded environmet should be no problem.

I cannot tell you how the performance of this is as I don't know your specific requirements so you have to determine this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded Java DB count-db (https://github.com/koendeschacht/count-db) provides an increaseCount method in its API which should answers to this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.mapdb.org. It is very high performance and offers a very familiar API (Java Map).